# Method for HMServiceGroup in Homekit

Tags: swift, homekit

I am trying to using HMServiceGroup method in my app to handle all accessories at a time. But not success. Please tell me simple method for handle accessories using HMServiceGroup method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the services are of the same type, you can use a loop like this for specific characteristic types or use a big switch statement

```
for service in serviceGroup.services {
    for characteristic in service.characteristics {
        if characteristic.characteristicType == HMCharacteristicTypePowerState {
          //turn on or off whatever you want to do 
        }
    }
}
```

or to access the accessory you can do

```
for service in serviceGroup.services {
    if let accessory = service.accessory {
         //do whatever you need here
    }
}
```

Comment: how to access single light or bulb.

Comment: How to pick single accessory from accessories list.

Comment: are you asking in a service group?  or in general accessory list from home?

Comment: I have edited the above code to get the accessory from the service.  If you need an accessory list from the home, the home has a "accessories" property.  So you can do the same as above  "for accessory in home.accessories"

Comment: Thanks @Maria for response.

Comment: Yup, approximate done. Thanks again @Maria <Specialist Homekit Developer>